# Is it a good practice for angular Directive append itself (selector) into the document?

Tags: angular, directive

I am making a modal dialog with selector:`<test-modal>` using ng-bootstrap. I originally want to make it as a component. But then it will be like navbar which I need to put it in AppComponent and every page sharing same modal component. The logic seems incorrect.

So I try to make a directive than allow every page can have it own modal. But then I have put the `<test-modal>` in every component which "may" need modal. So every page no matter will prompt the modal or not will have to include this code. I am not sure if it is normal practice.

Then I find out this page:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/25/angular-6-custom-modal-window-dialog-box
it makes modal as a dynamic directive and will append the `<test-modal>` to the document html just when it is needed and the directive is being called. Is it the best practice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use primeng or angular-material modal.

Comment: I am using ng-bootstrap modal as base. I want to make it more easy to use so I wrap it to my custom directive. So when I need modal (different msg every time), I can simple initialize the directive and modal come out. Is my concept correct?

Answer (score 0):

`Dynamic adding components or directives` is a technique documented in Angular as it offers a way to add component/ directives dynamically, such as the moment we want to use 
 not when application is bootstrapping. It's a normal practice in Angular and the document is specified [here](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

One important thing is that it will not destroy but add new component every time it's triggered which could lower performance of application from time to time. So simply add `one or limited number of dynamic components` and try to re-use will help to improve performance. In your case, to `populating a modal`, it should be adding only one component to wrap a modal, then output different message every time it's called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me have a look to the document.. But if using a component to wrap a modal, which means I must put selector <test-modal> in AppComponent's template? So <test-modal> have to be here even client doesn't need to prompt modal? Or is there any better way ?

Comment: There is no need to add `<test-modal>` as `dynamic component loading` helps you to do it. There is an example in the document i mentioned above which help you to achieve this.

Comment: but in the url example,`<app-ad-banner>` is required to embed the dynamic component inside. So in my case, I have to make a `<xx-modal>` and then embed `<test-modal>` in it using viewContainerRef? But the `<xx-modal>` is required to put in Appcomponent template. I don't know if i understand it correctly.